# Change embed options on Vimeo when using popcorn.js

Tags: popcornjs

My question is simple. Can you change the embed options (e.g., hide the title, your avatar, etc) on a vimeo video that is being played via Popcorn.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, as long as you use the new Vimeo "wrapper." (The original player modules are being deprecated as of Popcorn 1.4.)

The wrapper is here:

https://github.com/mozilla/popcorn-js/blob/master/wrappers/vimeo/popcorn.HTMLVimeoVideoElement.js

You also need to include [this file](https://github.com/mozilla/popcorn-js/blob/master/wrappers/common/popcorn._MediaElementProto.js) first.

By default, the Vimeo wrapper disables the title, byline and portrait.

**Edit**:
You just need three scripts from the popcorn-js repo, and include them in script tags in this order:

1. [popcorn.js](https://github.com/mozilla/popcorn-js/blob/master/popcorn.js)
2. [popcorn._MediaElementProto.js](https://github.com/mozilla/popcorn-js/blob/master/wrappers/common/popcorn._MediaElementProto.js)
3. [HTMLVimeoVideoElement.js](https://github.com/mozilla/popcorn-js/blob/master/wrappers/vimeo/popcorn.HTMLVimeoVideoElement.js)

Create a container element in which to put the video:

```
<div id="video"></div>
```

Instantiate the video wrapper and popcorn:

```
var video = Popcorn.HTMLVimeoVideoElement('#video');
video.src = 'vimeo url goes here';
var popcorn = Popcorn(video);
```

Comment: Could you give me a quick installation process for this? Thanks for the info regardless

Comment: That seemed to work, although now I can't seem to control the size of it. The video div has an inline style with width and height, which worked before, but with this new setup it doesn't. Also, is there any way to get rid of the embed icons and all that? Thank you much for your help, by the way.

Comment: You can set the size just as you would on a video element. `video.width = 640;` But you have to do it before you set the `src` property. I'll see if I can patch that and submit a pull request when I have a moment. It's an easy fix.

Comment: I don't believe Vimeo's API allows you to remove the UI. I'm afraid we're stuck with it. You can try using an invisible div to block mouse  hover, but it'll still be there when the video is paused.